# ConfigurationErrorsException "Invalid Key Value", What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have a simple console application that is designed to read a custom Configuration Exception (code below) when I run this I am getting a ConfigurationErrorsException with the message "Invalid Key Value" when calling ConfigurationManager.GetSection. Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

**Config File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MySection" type="ConsoleApplication1.MySection, ConsoleApplication1" />
  </configSections>
  <MySection>
    <add name="MyName" value="MyValue" />
  </MySection>
</configuration>
```

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MySection section = (MySection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MySection");

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }

    public class MySection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        public MyCollection Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return (MyCollection)this[""];
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new MyElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((MyElement)element).Name;
        }
    }

    public class MyElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ConfigurationProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled
  Message=Invalid key value. (C:\Users\martin.brown\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe.config line 7)
  Source=System.Configuration
  BareMessage=Invalid key value.
  Filename=C:\Users\martin.brown\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe.config
  Line=7
  StackTrace:
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\martin.brown\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 14
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not seen custom sections defined the way you are trying to do. You can however get it to work by making a few minor changes

Change your config from:

```
...
<MySection>
    <add name="MyName" value="MyValue" />
</MySection>
...
```

to:

```
...
<MySection>
    <MyElements>
        <add name="MyName" value="MyValue" />
    </MyElements>
</MySection>
...
```

and then modify your code slightly:

```
public class MySection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("MyElements", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public MyCollection Collection{get {return (MyCollection) this["MyElements"];}}
}

public class MyElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get {return (string) (base["name"]);}
        set {base["name"] = value;}
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("value")]
    public string Value
    {
        get {return (string) (base["value"]);}
        set {base["value"] = value;}
    }
}
```

(the `MyCollection` class remains unchanged)

This will then work, and will also enable you to add multiple values in your config:

```
...
<MySection>
    <MyElements>
        <add name="MyName1" value="MyValu1e" />
        <add name="MyName2" value="MyValue2" />
    </MyElements>
</MySection>
...
```

Comment: It turns out the error was caused by me not getting the MyElement.Name property from the base ConfigurationElement's collection. Giving the default collection no name in the ConfigSection just means you can leave out the <MyElement> element. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I had the same issue not calling base["name"] on the properties.

Answer (score 3):

If it helps anyone, I had this same error but for a different reason.  In my custom ConfigurationElementCollection class, the GetElementKey() method was returning a value that was sometimes null:

```
protected override Object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
{
  return ((EmulatorPositionElement)element).Method;
}
```

More specifically, it was retrieving a nullable enumeration value from a custom ConfigurationElement object:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("method", IsRequired = true)]
public string MethodString
{
  get { return (string)this["method"]; }
  set { this["method"] = value; }
}

public Method? Method
{
  get { return (MethodString.Trim() == "*") ? null : (Method?)Enum.Parse(typeof(Method), MethodString.Trim(), true); }
  set { MethodString = (value == null) ? "*" : value.ToString(); }
}
```

I would get this error whenever there were child elements in the config file where this ConfigurationProperty value was null.

```
<position method="*" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              var section = (MySection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MySection");

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }

    public class MySection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)this["name"]; }
            set { this["name"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("value")]
        public string Value
        {
            get { return (string)this["value"]; }
            set { this["value"] = value; }
        }

    }

    public class MyCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new MyElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((MyElement)element).Name;
        }
    }

    public class MyElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)this["name"]; }
            set { this["name"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("value")]
        public string Value
        {
            get { return (string)this["value"]; }
            set { this["value"] = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a value the MyName key

```
<add name="MyName" value="your value" />
```